# Will componentDidCatch will be depreciated or I'm missing something?

Tags: reactjs

I'm curious what does "but this will be deprecated in a future release." means in the following note in the React documentation.

> In the event of an error, you can render a fallback UI with
> `componentDidCatch()` by calling `setState`, but this will be deprecated
> in a future release.

Since `componentDidCatch()` has been introduced in version 16, and it is recommended to use it for catching errors in component tree or component wrapped inside it, I am sure that this method will NOT be depreciated.

So, what will be depreciated -

The lifecycle method, or calling `setState()` in componentDidCatch?

Link to the doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidcatch

Comment: Link to the documentation page please, we have no idea the context of that statement without it.

Comment: "Use [`static getDerivedStateFromError()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromerror) to handle fallback rendering instead"

Comment: @JamesIves, added the link.

Comment: @ArmanCharan, I'm aware of it and the reason behind it, just curios what does this sentence mean.

Comment: My bad. The sentence suggests that `componentDidCatch()` will be deprecated. `this.setState()` is not going anywhere. If it was there would be a note in the [`this.setState()` section](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) @Faheem